# Get unlimited $_POST variables & list them

Tags: php, arrays, post

I want to receive unlimited $_POST variables including an additional number and turn them into arrays like paypal form does.

Example:

```
<form action="mysite">
<input name="productname" />
<input name="productname1" />
<input name="productname2" />
Etc....
</form>
```

I will turn that into a php array after receiving it:

```
products(gta,twilight,flowers,chocolate,ipod)
```

So that just to explain you, i want to list them as an invoice.

Note: Please don't suggest to use the productname[], i want to use preg match to do that 
Thanks

Comment: You'll run into trouble if you think you can have an unlimited number of $_POST (or $_GET) variables. Servers with the Suhosin patch have a default maximum value of 100 variables.

Comment: I added a solution which I think you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
<form action="mysite">
<input name="productname[]" />
<input name="productname[]" />
<input name="productname[]" />
Etc....
</form>
```

Then `$_POST['productname']` will be a numeric array with all your values.

If you can't control the form, you can build the array like this:

```
$res = array();
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if (preg_match('/^productname(\d{0,})$/', $k, $matches))
        $res[(int) $matches[1]] = $v;
}
// result in $res
```

Comment: Hi, i already know that, i wanna programatically to turn that into array using some preg match or something... thanks!

Comment: @David, can you clarify?  `$_POST['productname']` will already be an array.  You don't need to use `preg_match`.

Comment: I know that, but i want the form to be like paypal, they should add numbers to the end of variable

Comment: @David Why the hell would you want to replace an easily iterable structure like an array with that?...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if(strpos($name, 'productname') === 0) {
        // Do something with it
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they don't actually have to have numbers in the names, use:

```
<form action="mysite">
<input name="productname[]" />
<input name="productname[]" />
<input name="productname[]" />
Etc....
</form>
```

PHP will convert `productname` to an array.  The [FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) has more info on this feature.

Comment: Hi, i already know that, i wanna programatically to turn that into array using some preg match or something... thanks!